# Can't Display Special Characters Django/Python in Template/WebPage

Tags: python, mysql, django, utf-8, django-templates

I have a problem with special characters.

I am doing a mysql query using mysqldb. The database itself is in UTF-8 as well as the tables. The query has a result that, when running the query as a query itself, i get the correct result: Türkiye.

In MysqlDB, i am using the "charset = 'utf8', use_unicode = True" I also have "# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-" At the top of my python file. Additionally, i also have the variable set to

```
unicode(text)
```

However, it seems that no matter what i do, i cannot get the text to display as "Türkiye" And it always is displaying as "T\xfcrkiye"

Now, i could do a simply find replace, but the problem is, there are many other special characters used in other places as well. Too many to reliably use find/replace. What i want to do, is have this character be displayed and stored correctly in a variable as "Türkiye" and not "T\xfcrkiye"

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Get it to display where?

Comment: On the web page itself/TEmplate

Comment: You're using `{{ text }}` and it's only displaying "T\xfcrkiye", without the quotes or any other characters?

Comment: Yes, that is what is happening.

Comment: To a bit more specific, it is displaying other characters as well ( when they are others) but it is displaying T\xfcrkiye instead of Türkiye If i type the text plainly in the template, it will display correctly. But getting it from a query, it does not.

Comment: So no square brackets, parens, or quotes then?

Comment: brackets, parens, and quotes work i believe, but i wouldn't know as i don't have any rows in my database with those characters in them.

Comment: Django is generally good with Unicode. I would put some time into checking the data as it comes from the db. Running the shell and checking things like the type and what the second character looks like interactively, etc. You can spin your wheels forever if the data is stored in the database as the literal characters "\xfc", just for one unpleasant possibility.

Comment: If i run a sql query it displays correctly, how would i go about checking if it is stored in the DB as the literal characters?

Also, if it is stored as the literal characters, what would my options be?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-shell - that'll get you an interactive shell in which you can run the same queries your view uses. If the db content is bad you have a messy problem with no easy answer - people would have to know exactly what's in the db to help.

Comment: I mean, you're right that the fact that a SQL shell displays it correctly means it's probably not that exact problem, but ultimately you're not giving the Unicode object `u'T\u00fcrkiye'` or the UTF-8 encoded bytestring `'T\xc3\xbcrkiye'` to the templating engine, or (much less likely) you're running the string through something in a custom tag or filter that handles the encoding wrong. You need to figure out exactly what your query is getting from the db.

Answer (score 1):

Include this at the top of your HTML page/template

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

You should send the request as an html page, otherwise I don't think you will be able to output that character correctly.

Hope it works!

Comment: This didn't seem to work.

As an aside, i noticed that if i change the line for the text to be:

`text.encode('utf-8')`

That it now displays as `t\xc3\xbcrkiye` on the webpage

Comment: you can try encoding it with 'latin-1' while displaying in your template

`>>> print u'\xce\xb1'.encode('latin-1')
α`

see [str.encode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) and [Standard Encoding](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) for supporting more languages and dialects

Comment: Doing that gives me an error

`'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u0131'`

As i mentioned before, there are many other special characters in the text, i was just using the Türkiye as the example of the bunch

Comment: Well try other encoders some or the other will get a hit that's why I provided Standard Encoding list latin-1 usually takes care of many special alphabets try other encoders I'm sure some encoder will match.

Comment: i'm a bit confused by that though, utf-8 should take care of everything there. The problem is that if i do this and have just the single string or characters and use the utf-8 encoding, it appears to work fine, but when doing it from this query, for some reason it won't

Comment: OK this is taking longer than I expected but one last go [here](http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_latin_extended_a.asp) it gives a table for several special characters. See if it helps!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63450/discussion-between-abhi-and-user2146933).

Answer (score 0):

```
In [5]: a = u"T\xfcrkiye"

In [6]: print a
Türkiye
```

I think you are printing str not unicode string. Try: var = u'{}'.format(text)